# CakePHP Error: The requested address was not found on this server

Tags: php, cakephp

I have an action which gets the `id` from user and deletes the item related to; Requests are like this:

/managers/delete_item/5
But this occurs error:

> Error: The requested address /managers/delete_item/5 was not found on this server

This is the `delete_item` in controller:

```
function delete_item($id = null)
{
    $this->item->id = $id;
    $this->item->status = 0;
    if ($this->data) {
        if ($this->item->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Removed', 'default', array('class' => 'success-msg'));
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'managers', 'action' => 'discount'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('ERR', 'default', array('class' => 'error-msg'));
        }
    } else {
        $this->data = $this->item->read();
    }
}
```

However i have some similar actions in my controller which doing such thing Deleting, Editing... and not occurs the error.

Please help.

Comment: Check exact error message using following steps - 
1. application->config->core.php : Configure::write('debug', 2);
2. Refresh the page
3. You will get error stack with exact reason.

Share complete stack here so I can help you out...


Please alos mention which cakephp version your are using, is it 2.0+ or <2.0

Comment: No error reported from debugger related to this issue. the version is 1.2.1.8004

Comment: With `$this->item->status=0` i'm trying to change the `status` field in the Database then save them. what's wrong with that?

Comment: @user3642119 You should use `saveField()` for these kind of events. See http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#saving-your-data (scroll down a little bit for the `saveField()` part).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're looking for the `saveField()` method for this action. This just updates a single field in your model. This should do the trick:

```
function delete_item($id = null) {
    $this->Item->id = $id;

    // Try to update the status
    if ($this->Item->saveField('status', 0)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Removed', 'default', array('class' => 'success-msg'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash('ERR', 'default', array('class' => 'error-msg'));
    }

    // Always redirect, regardless of the outcome (to make sure no view is needed)
    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'managers', 'action' => 'discount'));
}
```